# Rule of thumb: What is "enough" data to consider a neural network over traditional ML algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I know that neural networks require more data than "traditional" ML algorithms like e.g. kNN or linear regression, or at least will do better with larger datasets. And that with few data, those traditional ML algorithms will most likely outperform NNs.

But, as a rule of thumb, *what's considered enough data (in terms of rows and columns) to choose a NN over traditional ML algorithms?*